# It's possible to merge a phone call with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, telephony

I would like to know if it is possible, during a phone call, to merge the current call with another call made from an app developed with Flutter?

During a phone call, I want to be able to add another call, from my app, and merge both calls automatically.

I've been unable to find a flutter package with telephony control.

Regards

Comment: That's not how any of it works.. It's like asking to get your physical mail to your email address

Comment: If you are talking about a cellular call, then no.  Call merging happens in the telephony network,, not the device.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answers. Really, I don't want to do the merge in the phone. Rather, I just want to launch the merge process from my app. Just like the actual phone interface does. It's possible?

Comment: Do you mean changing two regular calls to one conference call? I think it is not builtin in the default Flutter library...

Comment: so it's like you are on ongoing call at that time some one calls you and you want to merge that call with existing one through you app button ?

Comment: Yes @AkshayGupta, that's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think for `iOS`, better to use the `CallKit framework` to handle call management and in `Android`, better to use the `Android TelephonyManager` and `Call APIs` to control phone calls programmatically, so let me show you with an example, but be aware this is just a basic example to demonstrate the concept of call merging!!!

in `iOS` and in `Objective-C`

```
#import <CallKit/CallKit.h>

@interface CallMergeManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallController *callController;
@end

@implementation CallMergeManager

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _callController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)mergeCalls {
    CXSetMutedCallAction *mergeAction = [[CXSetMutedCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:[NSUUID UUID] muted:NO];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:mergeAction];
    [self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"merging calls error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

and in `Android` with `java`, something like this :

```
public class CallMergeManager {
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

    public CallMergeManager(Context context) {
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    }

    public void mergeCalls() {
        telephonyManager.mergeCalls();
    }
}
```

now, in `Flutter`, you can define a platform channel to communicate with the native code like below for both of them (iOS and Android)

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

final MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('call_merge_channel');

Future<void> mergeCalls() async {
  try {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('mergeCalls');
  } catch (e) {
    print('merging calls error: $e');
  }
}
```

and for invoking the `mergeCalls` from `Flutter` to trigger call merging:

```
mergeCalls();
```

Good luck!